# Where do I find database panel for SQLite in IntelliJ 13.0?

Tags: android, sqlite, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 13.0. I googled for sqlite, but I did not find database option at view > Tool Window. What is is missing in my IntelliJ IDEA 13.0?

Comment: Do you have the free Community Edition or the commercial Ultimate Edition?

Answer (score 5):

[There is no database support in the free Community Edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html). That is only part of the commercial Ultimate Edition.